# have relation with many rows VS save all data in json column?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I use mysql and laravel 9.
I have a products table and a details table.
details data is array of objects like this:

```
[
{name:name, data:{color:#000 , font:sans} , type:type},
{name:title, data:{id:[1,2,3]} , type:type},
....
]
```

I use this relation:

```
 public function details()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Detail::class);
}
```

each of products has at least 20 details row.

If I store all details data in one JSON column inside of products table. It's faster?
Or have a details table with 2 billion rows. And in every request for product I have to get all details rows!

In other words, having one-to-many relation in big database is faster or store all data in on JSON column?

Comment: Storage doesn't have performance. Queries have performance. It's impossible to say for certain if JSON would be better for your case, because you have not shown a specific query that you need to optimize.

Comment: "have to get all details rows!" -- Don't you mean "have to get all **20+** rows"?

Comment: @RickJames yes. i have to get  all 20+ rows in details table.

Answer (score 1):

Any data elements that will be used for filtering (in `WHERE`) or sorting (in `ORDER BY`) should be in columns.

Else, can you think of the data as an "opaque" blob of stuff -- like a JPG?  That is, if you are simply holding some data for someone else *but do not need to look at what is in it*, then JSON / BLOB / etc is the 'right' way to store it.

Comment: thank you  
I use your suggestion @RickJames